# Spinnaker not showing images in pipeline trigger

Tags: docker, cicd, aws-ecr, spinnaker

I have a Spinnaker pipeline which I am trying to add an automated trigger from an ECR repo. Spinnaker lets me add the docker registry as per the following spinnaker [doc link](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/docker-registry/#amazon-elastic-container-registry-ecr), however I am unable to select an image when setting up the trigger. I've looked around on google and came up short of others having this issue. The closest I found was someone who lost it after an upgrade on a pretty old version.

TDLR: Can't see docker image/repo when adding automated trigger on an ECR repo

Comment: I just tried specifying the repos as a param and that now has it so I can not see the account at all where I could before

Comment: did you ever fix this issue? im also getting this issue